# javascript comma doesn't encoded

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to encode this text from

> 2016, Odd Semester, Periode 1

to

> 2016%2C%20Odd%20Semester%2C%20Periode%201

but i can't encode the comma.

it show like this

> 2016,%20Odd%20Semester,%20Periode%201

here my code

```
var Term = '2016, Odd Semester, Periode 1'
encodeURI(Term);
```

Comment: use `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: or use `encodeURIComponent` instead

Comment: This function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ # (Use [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) to encode these characters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent()`:

```js
var foo = encodeURIComponent('2016, Odd Semester, Periode 1');
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use encodeURIComponent(). It should suffice.

The encodeURIComponent() function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters:

> , / ? : @ & = + $ #

```
var Term = '2016, Odd Semester, Periode 1'
encodeURIComponent(Term);
```